# How to use the constraint 'delegate'

Tags: c#

C# now allows delegate constraints in generics. As I was trying to learn the new feature, I could not come with a single practical way of using it. As others have been asking for this feature for years, I am obviously missing the point here.

```
public class Test<TDelegate> where TDelegate : Delegate
{
    readonly TDelegate fd; // no way to call this 
    public event TD Evt; // not even legal
}
```

How does a class do anything useful with a generic parameter that is a delegate?

Comment: The most obvious thing to do with a delegate is `.Invoke` it. (And `event` is just syntactic sugar around the other operations too, like `.Combine`.)

Comment: [I found this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#delegate-constraints), for what it's worth.

Comment: @DavidG: the question is about what to do now that you *can* constrain the type to a delegate, in the most recent versions of C#. Actually, it's described [pretty exhaustively in the proposal document](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/158), along with demonstrations of use.

Comment: Which turns the question in something like "can you explain the docs to me"?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ugh yes, I should have read the question properly!

Comment: Having written a test app, I can't actually think of a single reason why this is useful either!  Good Question!  Why not just have a class that constrains to Action type instead of Delegate, what's the difference?

Comment: @DanRayson: The difference is that with Action you would have a signature for invoking it. I had hoped this feature could be useful for adding something to any delegate, like an invocation count.

Comment: The CLR permits this, mostly because it didn't have a good reason not to and some kind of language may make the syntax sensible.  I think F# is such a language.  But C# is not, the only thing you can do is DynamicInvoke().  Which completely defeats the point of type-safe generic code.  The current C# team no longer has a benevolent dictator, like Anders Hejlsberg used to be, that has the power to say "no!"  Avoid it, but you have it if you can't think of a better way to do it.

Comment: Less pessimistically, the fact that the constraint is now possible (as it was an explicit and senseless restriction in C# itself) now opens the door for actually building on it and making it more useful. The current C# team is *also* augmented by a bunch of volunteers contributing code, so it's not such a bad thing to have more people say "yes" every now and then...especially when it's something that doesn't take the language in a completely new direction.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is:

```
public static void Foo<T>(T t) where T : System.Delegate
{
    t.DynamicInvoke();
}
```

For some reason, the normal `Invoke()` isn't a valid method that can be used.

Comment: "For some reason".

Comment: That's what I said, yes.

Comment: @AustinWBryan Ed Plunkett irony was probably because it is for a very specific reason: `Invoke` is strongly typed and has the exact number of parameters (and the exact return type) of the delegate. Clearly this changes based on the delegate `T` (that is unknown at compile time). `DynamicInvoke` doesn't know anything about the delegate, and is totally universal (it has as a parameter a `object[]`, and as the return type a `object`)

Comment: Indeed, all you need to do is look at the [System.Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx) to see it doesn't have an `Invoke` method.